# On click button apply event only for it top ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm recently learning JS/jQuery and I need help to apply a particular style/class to the top div when click the button inside it, but the problem is that the html has different sections with the same button and the same class on ancestor, and I want it to **only apply** to the actual div that contains the triggered button.

HTML:

```
<div class="class">
    <div>
        <div>
            <button data-action="action">

<div class="class">
    <div>
        <div>
            <button data-action="action">
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('[data-action="action"]').click(function() {
    $(".class").addclass("new-class")
})
```

With this code obviously `new-class` is applied to all existing `class` classes regardless of the activated button.

Thanks!

Comment: try `$(this).closest(".class").addclass("new-class")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code :

```
$('[data-action="action"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.class').addclass("new-class")
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "closest" which selects the first ancestor with a selector passed (in  this case, first ancestor with "class" classname). The $(this) selector applies to the specific element that is clicked, in this case.

```
$('[data-action="action"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".class").addclass("new-class")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parent for the clicked element like this:

```
$('[data-action="action"]').click(function() {
    $this.parents(".class").addclass("new-class")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide id for the div along with class as..

```
<div class="class" id = "my_id">
<div>
    <div>
        <button data-action="action">

<div class="class">
<div>
    <div>
        <button data-action="action">
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('[data-action="action"]').click(function() {
$("#my_id .class").addclass("new-class")
```

})

try this it will work

Comment: Your code would not work `$("#my_id .class")` say that `my_id` has a child that has a class called class. Second, adding a div dont solve the OP question